# IBM IB 9 and MQ set max number of messages in minute that may be placed in queue

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

So I have IIB 9 and WMQ. For example there are two local queues Q1 and Q2. From Q1 messages goes to Q2. May I somehow filter how much messages in minute may go from Q1 to Q2? I want Q1 not to place more than N messages in minute to Q2, but I also don't want to lose messages from Q1 and I don't wnat to override messages in Q2. Just maybe turn off the ability to place in Q2 from Q1 for X seconds if Q1 reached it's limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using IBM Integration Bus to build your messages flows you can do this.

```
MQ Input (Q1) --> Mediation --> MQ Output (Q2)
```

You can create a Workload Management Policy in IBM Integration Bus 9.0.

In this kind of policy you can define the processing rate and attach this to the message flow.

[Configuration](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bn34263_.htm)